# add javascript libary with jquery dependency to angular 9

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to use `watermark.js` in my angular app to add watermarks to images before uploading them.

from what i remember, what I did should suffice to make this work:

download

```
npm i --save watermark.js
```

add to `scripts` tag in `angular.json`

```
 "scripts":[
    "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "./node_modules/watermark/dist/jquery.watermark.min.js"
],
```

use it in a Component

```
declare var watermark: any;
...
watermark(args)
```

but i get

`ERROR ReferenceError: watermark is not defined`

I also tried to declare it as a module by creating `src/@types/watermark/index.d.ts` and including `src/@types` it in `tsconfig->typeRoots`.

```
declare module 'watermark'
```

and then importing

```
import * as w from 'watermark';
```

But with this the build fails because it cannot find the module 'watermark'.

doing the same with jquery works

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
...    
$(window).ready(console.log('test'))
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

According to watermark page: https://lelinhtinh.github.io/watermark/

```
$(function() {
  $('.img_awesome').watermark();
});
```

so in your component get a handle on a dom element with jQuery then:

```
$(<selector>).watermark();
```

for this you need to: `declare var $:any;`

Comment: I hate this... everytime I want to add an jquery library I have to do something like this and it's horribly ugly to declare $ as any ... There is no other way?

Comment: @SebastianCiocarlan not sure I get you, `any` is the problem?

Comment: I agree this is problematic. `any` removes IntelliSense and type checking for anything that touches the plugin. In the past I couldn't find a way to add jQuery with types in an existing Angular project. I ended up just removing any plugin that relied on jQuery.

Comment: Yep @robert, its so unelegant.